# Bit String evaltuation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Im trying to figure out what this question is trying to find?

Evaluate: 
(01011^11001)v 01110 =? 
(11011 v 01010) ^ (10001 v 11011) = ?

Initially i said the first one was False, and the second was true, but that was incorrect

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you're supposed to do here is bit string flicking; you should perform bitwise operations on each pair of strings, and your result should be a string of the same length as one of your input. I'll do the first for you, and hopefully you'll be able to get the second by yourself.

I am a little confused by your notation here; in C++, the caret means "exclusive or", but judging by the context, I'll assume that ^ is and and v is or, though the standard notations for each are & and | respectively.

01011 ^ 11001 means you look at both strings at each index and perform the logical operator on the two values. Here, we have "and", which gives true, or 1, if both values are true, and 0 otherwise. In the first place, we have 0 & 1 = 0. Next, we have 1 & 1 = 1, and then 0 & 0 = 0. Continuing in this fashion, we get 01001. This can be seen as showing where they both have 1, and 0 everywhere else.

Next, we have 01001 v 01110. Here, the operation is "or", which gives false, or 0, if both values are false, and 1 otherwise. In the first place, we have 0 & 0 =0. Next, we have 1 & 1 = 1, and then 0 & 1 = 1. Continuing in this fashion, we get 01111. This can be seen as showing where they both have 0, and 1 everywhere else.

Thus, the answer to the first should be 01111.

Answer (score 0):

It usually means bitwise operation in the context of computer programming, for example $(01001\wedge11001)\vee01110=01001\vee01110=01111$.